# Do I need reintegrate when merging permanent branches?

Tags: svn

This is my Layout

```
/trunk
/branches/qa
/branches/dev
```

I don't intend to delete any of this branches in the future

Do I need to use `--reintegrate` when merging from DEV to QA?
Or from QA to /trunk

Thanks

Comment: What are the exact relationships between the branches? Is `qa` a branch of `dev`, and `dev` a branch of `trunk`, or have both been branched off of `trunk`?

Comment: `qa` and `dev` are both branches of `trunk`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If merge direction is always the same (i.e. you do not merge from qa to dev, only dev->qa), simple merge is enough.

A separate mode (reintegration) was needed to avoid unneeded merges. In "feature branch" scenario the feature branch will have two type of changes in it:

1. regular commits
2. merges from trunk

When we want to put the feature into trunk we want to merge only (1). But if we will use default merging mechanism, SVN will also try to merge (2) into trunk which will lead to conflicts or hidden errors, because those changes are already there.

Comment: I do not agree with this. Given the names of the branches, it is a relatively safe assumption that there will be bi-directional merges between `dev` and `qa`

Comment: @SameerSingh: it depends, assumption of one-way merges was mostly a guess, but it's based on two merge examples given in the question

Answer (score 1):

Using a reintegration merge between two branches (including `trunk`), and intending to keep the source branch around, is generally a bad idea. There are weird issues with using a branch which was the source in a previous reintegration merge, in a future merge.

The general solution is to reintegration-merge the source branch into `trunk` (which *should* be the target branch), and then drop-and-recreate the source branch off `trunk` post-merge.

You, however, want to do something slightly different.

Should you conduct a reintegration merge between `dev` and `qa`? My advice is to avoid a reintegration merge, use a sequential or differential merge instead, and follow the path of creation when merging (see below).

Normally, if you wanted changes merged from `dev` to `qa`, you would merge `dev` into `trunk` (and commit) and then `trunk` into `qa` (and commit). In other words, you follow *the path of creation*. This gives a nice, clean view of the merge history when auditing your commits and merges.

If this is not possible, then you need to be extra careful conducting branch-to-branch merges, and these should generally be limited to sequential merges only. Then, when the time comes to merge either `dev` or `qa` into `trunk`, it will be much easier to do.

Hope this helps.